# How can I view all my network questions by newest first?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I go to my network profile, I can see my "top questions" under the "Top" tab.  How can I see my questions across the network ordered by newest first, though?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible *in date* order...only by votes

Comment: You can get all _posts_ (Q+A) ordered by date though

Comment: Perhaps SEDE Master could help (I'm not). Meanwhile, I only found a way to list the latest 100 *posts* (Q&A) ordered by date from [Network profile - Activity - Posts](https://stackexchange.com/users/59775/jez?tab=activity)